# Fullcalendar automatically swaps colors when multiple events coincide on the same dates/times

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar 6 to display three distincts calendars:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    height: 'auto',
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
    locale: 'fr',
    buttonText: {
      week: 'S',
      list: 'L'
    },
    allDaySlot: false,
    nowIndicator: true,
    hiddenDays: [0, 6],
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    slotMinTime: '08:00:00',
    slotMaxTime: '20:00:00',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'timeGridWeek,listMonth'
    },
    dayMaxEvents: true, 
    displayEventTime: true,
    eventSources: [
      // First calendar
      {
        url: url1,
        color: '#FFCC00',
        textColor: 'black'
      },
      // Second calendar
      {
        url: url2,
        color: '#2A7FFF',
        textColor: 'white'
      },
      // Third calendar
      {
        url: url3,
        color: '#66C902',
        textColor: 'black'
      },
    ],
    eventContent: function (info) {
      // Get the event title
      var title = info.event.title;
      // Extract the first two letters of the title
      var elements_temp = title.split(":");
      var displayTitle = elements_temp.slice(0, 2).join(":").replace(':', '\n');
      // Create a new event element with the shortened title
      var eventElement = document.createElement('div');
      eventElement.innerText = displayTitle;
      eventElement.style.backgroundColor = info.event.backgroundColor;
      return { domNodes: [eventElement] };
    },
    eventDidMount: function (info) {
      my_display = 'test'
      // Attach tooltip to event elements
      tippy(info.el, {
        content: my_display,
        allowHTML: true,
        arrow: true,
      })
    },
    eventClick: function (info) {
      info.jsEvent.preventDefault(); // prevent the default click action
    },
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

I've encountered a peculiar bug demonstrated in the attached video. Essentially, when switching between views (moving forward and backward), the colors intermittently swap on events that occur simultaneously or at the exact same time/date.

[image]

Comment: is it a bug or doesn't it have a priority option it doesn't know what to display first?

Comment: I would add text to those events to tell if the colors or just the events are swapping

Comment: Yes. This was the reason. When the text is different there is no swapping. Thanks !!!!